# Firebase Query an Array of Keywords

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: That's my Firebase Structure]

My code

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("stock");
Query i = myRef.orderByChild("keywords").equalTo("Hammer");
i.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue());    
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

My Problem: I wanna query only one item with the Keyword eg. "Hammer", but I only getting null as value. If I query like "orderByChild("keyword").equalTo("Hammer")" I'm getting the same null value. Please help me.

Comment: Please read this guide for asking questions over here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: add the code as text. and include what `myRef`is refering to.

Comment: @adolfosrs there is no "stock" node in the database provided

Comment: Why would you use a realtime database to store this static data? It seems like overkill

Comment: "stock" is there, you only can't see it on the picture

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: HEy @MarvinBöddeker, let me know if my answer helped you or if you still have any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

`orderByChild` will only look into the next level childs for the branch you are refering in `/stocks`. Your code would only work if you had the child `keywords/0/keyword` right bellow `/stocks`. Since its under `/stocks/inserate/0` it wont work.

```
Query i = myRef.child("inserate/0/keywords").orderByChild("keyword").equalTo("Hammer");
```

This will do the trick but it might not be exactly what you want. If you want to search in all the `iserates` childs you should do some refactoring into your database.